# zipping specific files in subfolder with make

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, zip

I have a makefile in which I want to zip several files together, but use a subfolder as the root of the zip file. Currently I am using this:

```
 kountdown.zip: $(SRCS)
     cd $(SRCDIR) && zip -r --filesync ../kountdown.zip .
```

Where `$(SRCS)` is a list of my source files in `$(SRCDIR)`. This works, but I only want to include the files in `$(SRCS)` in the zip file, not the whole directory. The problem is that the paths in `$(SRCS)` is relative to the location of the makefile, not `$(SRCDIR)`. I could make a second variable for the paths relative to `$(SRCDIR)`, but I would like to avoid duplicating the list. Ideally I would like a way to run zip in the current directory, but use a sub-directory as the root of the zip file. But from all of my searching it looks like this isn't possible. Any ideas?

I am using linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
 kountdown.zip: $(SRCS)
     cd $(SRCDIR) && zip -r --filesync ../kountdown.zip $(subst $(SRCDIR)/,,$(SRCS))
```

That assumes `$(SRCDIR)` doesn't already have a `/` in it.  If it does, remove it from the `subst` statement above.

This should also work:

```
 kountdown.zip: $(SRCS)
     cd $(SRCDIR) && zip -r --filesync ../kountdown.zip $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,%,$(SRCS))
```